# adb error on Android SDK. Using Linux Ubuntu 64 bit 12.10

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu-12.10

I looked on this site for this error I'm encountering:

```
Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
Unable to run 'adb': Cannot run program "/home/ariel/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory.
Starting ADB server failed (code -1).
```

I've used this command on the terminal provided from this topic.

[Android SDK on a 64-bit linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710499/android-sdk-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine/10473415#10473415)

EDIT:
I've tried using this command on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Sadly, it did nothing and it showed this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6-i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libc6-i386' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What happens if you enter this command: /home/ariel/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools/adb

Comment: @JonWillis: This shows up at the terminal: bash: cd: /home/ariel/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools/adb: Not a directory

Comment: Do: $ sudo apt-get update; apt-cache search ia32-libs; to see if the libs are found

Comment: I got this in the terminal: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Is it because I have ubuntu 64 bit? I tried everything including this http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html  I wanted to use linux because I want to focus on programming and to stay a way from distractions(games).

Comment: I tried installing these commands: apt-get install ia32-libs and i get an error in the terminal: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
This is really a troublesome issue

Comment: adb is an executable, not a directory. why were you trying to cd into it?

Comment: @JonWillis: I see. Its an executable. Sorry, I'm a newb to linux. Its been giving me issues and I dont know why since I tried everything from other posts. I just reinstalled linux and going to try the troubleshoot again

Comment: Finally! It worked! I guess if everyone tried all the commands I posted above and get errors from the terminal, they may need to reinstall linux due to missing packages(ia32-libs etc...).

Comment: Welcome to unix-like-land. I think you'll learn to love it. Cheers

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same problem, but it's fine now with these commands :

***`sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386`

for running the emulator you need that additional package:

***`sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386`

then install ia32-libs:

***`apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: This worked for me on 13.10, but I had to use `sudo apt-get install lib32z1` instead of `ia32-libs` at the end.

Comment: @ross with the assist... this is confirmed on Xubuntu 14.04 64bit too

Answer (score 4):

You need to add i386 packages to apt

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Answer (score 2):

I just used

```
sudo apt-get install lib32bz2-1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, one may try :

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```