# Eclipse - All tools & API's Installed R still not autogenerating

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, r.java-file

I am using Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04. I have created a new Android Application Project, gave it a default name. It's being compiled with 4.4. I have created this project in my workspace. Right from the get-go I do not have R generating when I do have EVERY single install-able package installed.

Every single "solution" I have seen as far as this topic goes had to do with Build Tools not being installed or xml issues. I have tried removing dependencies, purging eclipse, and reinstalling. After re-installing, I re-install all packages, but it still is not generating R.

I am new to Android Development, and I am at a serious loss for words. Whatever further information I need to provide let me know. I am really looking forward to getting started but this is obviously holding me back.

Side Note: I have also tried cleaning the project, restarting eclipse, and restarting my computer.

EDIT: This has to be some setting outside the development environment. I downloaded android-studio and I STILL get that R cannot be resolved to a variable. Seriously at a loss...

Comment: eclipse? my computer? 5+ each

Comment: I tried to post a picture of my project directory, but I won't be able to do that until 10 rep.

Comment: I figured it out. After installing a different IDE and the same results occured, I figured it had to be something with the system. I did not realize the fact that I was on a 64bit OS would have caused a conflict, but I guess it did. 

After following the steps provided by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421171/adb-error-on-android-sdk-using-linux-ubuntu-64-bit-12-10

I was able to successfully create a new project that created the r file...

I cannot answer my own question for 8 hours though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. After installing a different IDE and the same results occured, I figured it had to be something with the system. I did not realize the fact that I was on a 64bit OS would have caused a conflict, but I guess it did. After following the steps provided by stackoverflow.com/questions/14421171/… I was able to successfully create a new project that created the r file...